# plotting sinc(x)*sinc(y) surface in latex

Tags: pgfplots

I try to plot a cardinal sinus in 2D with LaTeX but it is not working at all as the symetry axes are not the right ones.
The ones I get are the first and second bisections of the plan while it should be the X and Y axes.

Below is my code.
I have seen on other posts the fact of putting degrees in the sines and radian outside the sine but still not working.

Any idea? thx

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      view={0}{90}, % Vue de dessus
      xlabel=$x$,
      ylabel=$y$,
      zlabel=$z$,
      colormap/jet,
      colorbar,
      shader=interp,
      ]
      \addplot3[
        surf,
        domain=-0.1:0.1,
        domain y=-0.1:0.1
        ]
      {sin(167*x)/(167*x)*sin(167*y)/(167*y)}; % 167 = 1e-4/(6e-7)
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Représentation du sinus cardinal en deux dimensions.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of 167?  I'm not understanding what you mean by "the first and second bisections of the plan[e?]".  Regardless, I think your problem might be that this setup is evaluating at x=0 and y=0.  Do you get something closer to your expectations with barely nonsymmetric domains?

Comment: If you use `samples=20` (to avoid calculating in x=0 or y=0) the picture is much better (and I think correct).

Comment: in diffraction the argument of the sinc is pi*square width/wavelenght/focal length*x) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you need? If you compute `sinc(x) = sin(x)/x` and `x` is in radians, you have to convert to degrees only the argument of the `sin` function, I think:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      view={0}{90}, % Vue de dessus
      xlabel=$x$,
      ylabel=$y$,
      zlabel=$z$,
      colormap/jet,
      colorbar,
      shader=interp,
      ]
      \addplot3[
        surf,
        domain=-1:1,   %radians
        domain y=-1:1, %radians
        samples = 20,
        ]
      {sin(deg(x))/(x)*sin(deg(y))/(y)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Représentation du sinus cardinal en deux dimensions.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With more range and samples (but remember this is LaTeX, not Matlab!) you can see the "bigger picture":

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      view={30}{60}, % Vue de dessus
      xlabel=$x$,
      ylabel=$y$,
      zlabel=$z$,
      colormap/jet,
      colorbar,
      shader=interp,
      ]
      \addplot3[
        surf,
        domain=-10:10,
        domain y=-10:10,
        samples = 50,
        ]
      {sin(deg(x))/(x)*sin(deg(y))/(y)};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{Représentation du sinus cardinal en deux dimensions.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]